# Mapbox iOS equivalent to Android setOnPolylineClickListener

Tags: ios, mapbox, nativescript

I've reviewed the iOS Mapbox SDK and cannot find the equivalent to the Android SDK [setOnPolylineClickListener](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/map-sdk/5.1.2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/MapboxMap.html#setOnPolylineClickListener-com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.OnPolylineClickListener-).

The project is using NativeScript (not a problem) so the code will be TS calling the native iOS pieces from the Mapbox SDK.

Current approach:

```
 const shape = MGLShape.shapeWithDataEncodingError(
        geo,
        NSUTF8StringEncoding
      );
      const source = MGLShapeSource.alloc().initWithIdentifierShapeOptions(
        polylineID,
        shape,
        null
      );
      theMap.style.addSource(source);

      const layer = MGLLineStyleLayer.alloc().initWithIdentifierSource(
        polylineID,
        source
      );
```

I can't find anything in the API that allows someone to set a tap/click listener(event) on a shape or layer for iOS. Does the iOS SDK not expose anything similar to Android for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! From my [answer on GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/10934#issuecomment-358094159): 
You can use [`-mapView:didSelectAnnotation:`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.3/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapView:didSelectAnnotation:) to handle taps on a `MGLPolyline`. [This example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/line-geojson/) shows how to add a polyline with our annotations API.

With a `MGLLineStyleLayer`,  you will need to implement a tap gesture recognizer that [accesses visible features](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.3/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/Accessing%20the%20Underlying%20Map%20Data). See this [guide on gesture recognizers](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.3/gesture-recognizers.html) for information about built-in gesture recognizers.